# How to have the LMC(Little Man Computer) output digits that start with zero?

Tags: assembly, little-man-computer

I need to output binary conversions(which I understand how to do). The issue I am having is that the LMC seems to not be able to print three zeros or '000'. Any idea how to get the program to perform this behavior? If this is a terrible question please help me rephrase or point me to a resource, thank you very much.

Edit: The code I am using:

```
       LDA  first
       OUT
       HLT
first  DAT  001
```

or

```
       LDA  first
       OUT
       HLT
first  DAT  000
```

Neither worked for me until I switched assemblers.

Comment: You should show some code, what happens now and what you have tried so far to try and get your extra 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed assemblers. Turns out the one I was using doesn't support 0's before decimal digits.

Initial Assembler: The LMC Editor, Assembler, and Simulator found at http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/cs3011/LMC.html

Changed to: LMC from Durham University found at
https://community.dur.ac.uk/m.j.r.bordewich/LMC.html

Hope it is ok to post links clear like this an not href it.

Comment: which assembler did you change to?  (And which one didn't do what you wanted?)

Comment: Although one can argue that the LMC is supposed to work with 3 digits -- according to the story of the little man moving slips of paper --, it does not deal with formatting. Numbers are just that: numbers. 004 and 4 are the same numbers.